# Why is focusout event not triggering in jQuery with focusout method ?

Tags: jquery, events, handsontable

I'm using handsontable jQuery plugin. I'm trying to intercept when a user stops editing a cell. When you double click on a cell, a text area with class `handsontableInput` appears on the position of that cell.

Using jQuery I tried to get the callback whenever the user clicks elsewhere, thus loosing focus of the textarea.

Here is the simple focusout code:

```
$(".handsontableInput").focusout(function () {
    alert("LLL");
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEH5C/).

Also, would this work if the page with the handsontable was in a frame, and I clicked outside the frame?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the `.on` method:

```
$("#exampleGrid").on('focusout','.handsontableInput',function () {
    alert("LLL");
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/edi9999/HEH5C/1/

The issue with your code was that at the moment of the execution of `$(".handsontableInput")`, they was no element with this class, so the event was attached to no element.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation. I couldn't understand why it wouldn't work. It makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Delegate event like this:

```
$("#exampleGrid").on('focusout',".handsontableInput",function () {
    console.log("LLL");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation as `.handsontableInput` is being generated dynamically

```
$(document.body).on('focusout',".handsontableInput",function () {
    console.log("LLL");
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/HEH5C/2/

Answer (score 1):

There is already a handsontable event that does this.
You could use its own event:

```
afterChange (changes: Array, source: String)
```

Although the main description of this event is "Callback fired after one or more cells is changed" it is called even when there is no change, just with the `oldValue` and `newValue`  of the `changes` array being the same. Therefore, this event is called when editing ends and loosing focus, which is what you wanted.

For more detail on the handsontable events, look [here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events)